# Can't change bootstrap black header color in Rails, even with background-image: none

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I've been Googling this, well, for awhile, and having no luck at all despite having read and tried the solutions on almost every Stack Overflow thread I can find. So please bear with me if I'm missing something simple, but I'm at that point. You've been there, I'm sure.

As of right now, I'm still stuck with the black bar at the top of my rails app, and am having zero luck in terms of changing the color. I'm a relatively seasoned front-end guy, but this is totally eluding me, probably due to the SASS files.

At this point I've tried copying a giant reset CSS snippet (including the background-image: none attributes applied to the navbar) into my applications.css file. No dice. Then my styles.css.scss file. Nothing.

When I inspect the element it would appear that, despite these changes, nothing helps except unchecking all of these boxes:

[image: Unchecked Boxes]

Nonetheless, styling these in my stylesheet doesn't seem to have any effect. I assume that some other styles are taking precedence over my own, but I'm not sure where to look for them. I also may well be placing these new/reset styles in the wrong file -- entirely possible -- but I don't know where to put them. I honestly want to reset almost all of the styling and redo it using custom classes, but I can't get it to change in the first place. Some element colors change just fine, but this black bar isn't going anywhere.

Here's my _header.html.erb, which is rendering the header:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "inboundteamof1", '#', id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "About", '#' %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Dashboard", 'dashboard#index' %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Register", signup_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you share the html.erb of the file where the black bar is being rendered?  Sometimes the ordering of elements and the nesting can make bootstrap act a bit weird.

Comment: Added it. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into a problem with the fixed layout styling.

From the docs

> Body padding required
>
> The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add
>   padding to the top of the . Try out your own values or use our
>   snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.
>
> body { padding-top: 70px; }
>
> Make sure to include this after the core Bootstrap CSS.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Also worth checking, I'm pretty sure that you shouldn't be using the `.container` style in a nav.  The other thing that stands out is the use of the `<header>` tag, bootstrap doesn't usually use that.

I note that the link is to Bootstrap 3, so things may be slightly different with Bootstrap 2

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar

Comment: These are fantastic recommendations, but are they really going to change the coloring of the bar? Should I change it from <header> to <div>? Or <nav>?

Comment: Potentially yes!  Bootstrap builds styling on top of styling and is based on a combination of tag names and classes.  Which version are you using?

Comment: Interesting. Stuck on another problem at the moment, but I'll try that soon! Thanks for your help!